# webpage response using PHP

Tags: php

I have a form structure webpage written in PHP.  When information is submitted it gives a unique ID.

Now I want this unique ID to be used in a file.  For Example:

```
$input = "man.id: ".$id;
```

where `$id` is the response from the webpage.

`$input` is present in the same PHP file.

Comment: Your question is very difficult to understand. Are you trying to figure out how to write that input line into a file?

Comment: @John consider updating your question to better reflect what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of how to write (append) text to a file with PHP:

```
$id = GetID(); // GetID can return a value stored on disk that gets incremented
$input = "man.id: " . $id;

$logfile = "mypage.log";
$file = fopen($logfile, 'a'); // Try to open the file in Append mode
if($file) // If the file was opened successfully, i.e. if $file is a valid file pointer
{
  flock($file, LOCK_EX); // Exclusive lock
  fwrite($file, $input);
  fclose($file);
}
```